# change (NULL) to zero in R language

Tags: r

Good morning, everyone,
In the following R code, i want to change (NULL) value to zero. but instead it changes to NA value. Any ideas? Thank you. Dennis

Loss_df$os[Loss_df$os == "(Null)"] <- 0

Comment: Is your data character or factor?

Comment: When asking for help, you should include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Chances are your `os` column is a factor. Unclear whether you want it to be numeric or not.

Comment: Try `is.null(Loss_df$os)` in place of `Loss_df$os == "(Null)"`

Comment: thanks. the input value is just a value of : (Null).  the value (Null) shows in the report. i want to change zero.

Comment: thanks, figured out by changing to ifelse: ifelse(Loss_df$os =="(Null)", 0, Loss_df$os)